# Spinnaker file properties from remote jenkins

Tags: spinnaker

Is there a way to pass file.properties to spinnaker from remote jenkins server ?
My setup:

```
jenkins servers
spinnaker configured with jenkins server
Property File: file.properties
```

I added the file.properties to job workspace dir:

```
Type=name
```

I tried referencing it with spinakker spel :

```
${trigger.properties['Type']}
```

No use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure to follow all the instructions [here](http://www.spinnaker.io/docs/pipeline-expressions-guide#section-property-files), including archiving the properties file? You can also view the source JSON of your pipeline execution to see what the resolved trigger actually contains.